# Oracle 10g to know the timedifference between two rows in one table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
requestid   Date
2   12/22/2016 23:21
3   12/22/2016 23:21
1   12/22/2016 23:21
37  12/22/2016 23:20
156 12/22/2016 23:20
```

Could someone please help I want to know the time Difference between requestid 1 and 156?

I have tried the below query but not getting the proper output.

```
 Select A.IFCOMPONENTUID,A.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT, (A.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT - B.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT) AS timedifference from XA_CASA.CFX_FILE_PROC_STAT A
where INNER JOIN XA_CASA.CFX_FILE_PROC_STAT B On A.IFCOMPONENTUID = (B.IFCOMPONENTUID + 155)  and 
 order by FILERUNTIMEUID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to your construct...

```
SELECT
    A.IFCOMPONENTUID,
    A.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT,
    B.IFCOMPONENTUID CompareID
    (A.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT - B.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT) TimeDiff
FROM XA_CASA.CFX_FILE_PROC_STAT A
INNER JOIN XA_CASA.CFX_FILE_PROC_STAT B
    ON A.IFCOMPONENTUID = (B.IFCOMPONENTUID + 155)
WHERE A.IFCOMPONENTUID = 1
```

I would prefer having explicit IDs in the where clause for more flexibility to change IDs:

```
SELECT
    A.IFCOMPONENTUID,
    A.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT,
    B.IFCOMPONENTUID CompareID,
    (A.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT - B.FPROCSTAGESTARTDT) TimeDiff
FROM XA_CASA.CFX_FILE_PROC_STAT A
INNER JOIN XA_CASA.CFX_FILE_PROC_STAT B
    ON 1 = 1
WHERE A.IFCOMPONENTUID = 1
    AND B.IFCOMPONENTUID = 156
```